# Bitconnect balance not showing on my wallet

Tags: bitconnect-coin

I sent from Bitconnect platform to my QT wallet and still showing 0.00 BCC, even though the transactions is confirmed and sent since yesterday. Could anyone help me with this? This is all the info I have for the transaction in case it helps.

Bitconnect Wallet Address: 8QDhQ1vWkuR4L5h7E6vKm1tGVmsFzWUyW3
Transaction: 58066e3767dbc02c219d24ab2995723f88f552889c0e60385f607487c10b0acc
Block: 289640
Day/Time: 1/17/2018 14:06
Amount: 3.35790826

Comment: bitconnect is a scam, MLM scheme, and ponzi.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fully sync the wallet for it to show your balance.

If you'r using Windows there is a tutorial on how to sync your wallet.